# Reading the contents of a file whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: python, file, variables, directory

The following code first creates a list of all the files in a folder called films, then attempts to access the contents of a specific file. I know how to do this if the file's name is a literal, but can someone please explain how this can be done if the name of the file or the directory is a variable?

```
path = 'films'

from os import walk

f = []
for (filenames) in walk(path):
    f.extend(filenames) 
    break

listoffiles = f[2]
print("listoffiles: ",listoffiles)  
 
read = open('films/{listoffiles[0]}',"r")
print("read: ",str(read.read()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change it to be

```
read = open(f'films/{listoffiles[0]}',"r")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'films'

from os import walk

f = []
for (filenames) in walk(path):
    f.extend(filenames) 
    break

listoffiles = f[2]
print("listoffiles: ",listoffiles)  
 
read = open('sentences/'+listoffiles[0],"r")
print("read: ",str(read.read()))
```

Not sure of your logic, but you can compose a string using the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If the "file name is a variable" it is representing the string.

So you can do the following:

```
with open(filenames) as open_file: 
    print(open_file.readlines())
```

(Or in your case extend)